# UIview array sorted return error in swift4 "Bool' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body"

Tags: swift, sorting

I have download one library this is working in swift3 but it's return me error in swift4 . Here is code.

```
let vi = self.collectionView!.subviews.sorted {
    return $0.0.layer.zPosition < $0.1.layer.zPosition
}
```

I have to manage `layer zposition`  but it's not working in swift4 
I know this is sorted problem but i am cant able to found solution .May be solution something like this

```
subviews.sorted { (n1:Int, n2:Int) -> Bool in return n1 < n2 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have some extra stuff in your sorted block. Try this instead.

```
let vi = self.collectionView!.subviews.sorted {
    return $0.layer.zPosition < $1.layer.zPosition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$0.0` and `$0.1`. Because you will be provide two variables with name `$0` & `$1`.

```
let vir = self.subviews.sorted {
            return $0.layer.zPosition < $1.layer.zPosition
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you All OF You.

I have found the solution

```
 let vi = self.collectionView!.subviews.sorted {(n1:UIView, n2:UIView) -> Bool in return n1.layer.zPosition < n2.layer.zPosition}
```